# App crashes after updating to iOS sdk 8.0

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

Updated to iOS sdk 8.0.

App crashes with the error

```
[PFInternalUtils assertValidClassForQuery:] at PFInternalUtils.m:372

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x032d6df6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02f60a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x032d6d1d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
3                                0x000e60b2 +[PFInternalUtils assertValidClassForQuery:] + 324
4                                 0x000ce3cb -[PFQuery whereKey:equalTo:] + 91
5                                 0x000b7391 -[InboxViewController retrieveMessages] + 193
6                                 0x000b624c -[InboxViewController viewWillAppear:] + 236
7   UIKit                               0x01aa614f -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 545
8   UIKit                               0x01aa66ca -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 148
9   UIKit                               0x01ad8389 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 931
10  UIKit                               0x01ad8fdb -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 669
11  UIKit                               0x01ad9c52 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
12  UIKit                               0x01c4bebc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
13  UIKit                               0x019d59c0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 608
14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02f76771 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
15  QuartzCore                          0x00c9827f -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 152
16  QuartzCore                          0x00c8c105 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 397
17  QuartzCore                          0x00c8bf60 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
18  QuartzCore                          0x00bea676 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 284
19  QuartzCore                          0x00beba3c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 392
20  QuartzCore                          0x00cb1789 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
21  UIKit                               0x019487e6 -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 39
22  UIKit                               0x01949761 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3163
23  UIKit                               0x01961d30 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
24  UIKit                               0x01947d7f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
25  FrontBoardServices                  0x064069de __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
26  FrontBoardServices                  0x0640646f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
27  FrontBoardServices                  0x06418425 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 26
28  CoreFoundation                      0x031fa7a0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
29  CoreFoundation                      0x031f00b3 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
30  CoreFoundation                      0x031eff0b __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
31  CoreFoundation                      0x031ef1ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
32  CoreFoundation                      0x031eefdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
33  UIKit                               0x01947744 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
34  UIKit                               0x0194ae16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
35                                0x000b567d main + 141
36  libdyld.dylib                       0x04dddac9 start + 1
37  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

EDIT:

```
- (void)retrieveMessages {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
[query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog (@"Error:%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }
    else {
        //we found messages
        self.messages = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog (@"Retrieved %d messages", [self.messages count]);

    }

    if([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}];
 }



 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
if (currentUser){
    NSLog (@"CurrentUser:%@", currentUser.username);
}
else{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];

}

self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveMessages) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   }


 - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];

[self retrieveMessages];

}
```

Using parse.com as backened.

before update it was working fine.

Any idea please how to fix this error.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can we please have the code. Also, is the exception you're getting this one: `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)` ?

Comment: all i m getting is CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:]

Comment: Please could you paste the **full error log** into your question (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847798/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-nsexception-error-xcode).

Comment: updated my post pls check it

Comment: I've tried to answer the question the best I can, but please provide the problem code. Please bear in mind that I do not do iOS development (or even any mobile development at all!), but basic logic is the same in every programming language so I've tried to follow this.

Comment: @user1120133 Please post the code from `[InboxViewController retrieveMessages]` and `[InboxViewController viewWillAppear:]`.

Comment: pls check just updated my post

Comment: I've updated my answer, please provide feedback on the answer and if it solves your issue, mark it as the accepted answer (by clicking the tick below the voting buttons).

Answer (score 2):

This error seems to be occurring because you are executing a function where a user must be logged in, but isn't when the function is executed.
Looking at [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965934/cannot-do-a-comparison-query-for-type-null-when-setting-up-uinavigationcont), the specific error seems to be related to `4                                 0x000ce3cb -[PFQuery whereKey:equalTo:] + 91`.
Looking at the linked question above, the full problem statement may well be `[PFQuery whereKey:equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]`.

Looking at your code the following is the code that's the root of the problem:

```
[query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
```

As said before, you'll need to catch if a user isn't logged in and prevent the main code in the function from running by adding a `return`.

One of the answers from the linked question:

> I just ran into this and it was due to the fact that I was doing an equalTo:[PFUser currentUser] in a PFQuery but there was no logged-in user at that point.

As to why this started occurring when you upgraded to the iOS 8 SDK (you're using Xcode 6.0.1 & the latest Parse SDK, right?), I'm not sure; perhaps it has nothing to do with the upgrade and you changed something to make this error occur.